# why am I getting Unknown option: '--output-hashing' angular 9

Tags: angular-cli, angular9

we have updated our build command from

"start": "ng serve --configuration=dev --aot --o",

to

"start": "ng serve --configuration=dev --aot --output-hashing=all",

but when i build i am getting the below error

> Unknown option: '--output-hashing' npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR!
> errno 1 npm ERR! client-app@0.0.0 start: `ng serve --configuration=dev --aot --output-hashing=all` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the client-app@0.0.0 start script. npm ERR! This is probably
> not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output
> above.

any idea why and how to solve

Comment: `--output-hashing` is meant to be used with `ng build`, not `ng serve`

Comment: oh I see, thank you

Comment: @R.Richards but when specifying configurations, the serve command will log a warning about output hashing being unavailable. So there should be a way to disable the hashing while running serve.